# MongoDB Datefields Constantly Resetting to 1969

Tags: php, mongodb, date, datetime

I'm really confused and have been scratching my head over this for a few days now. I have a PHP script that stores some user profiles in a MongoDB. Users can login, change a few fields, and logout. When they login, it records the lastlogin date/time, and when you modify something it records the last modified date/time using the MongoDate object.

It works.. but sometimes.. and of course what appears randomly, the dates reset for specific documents to '`ISODate("1969-12-31T16:00:00-08:00")`'

My documents store the dates like:

```
dates: {
    created: ISODate("1969-12-31T16:00:00-08:00"),
    lastlogin: ISODate("1969-12-31T16:00:00-08:00"),
    modified: ISODate("1969-12-31T16:00:00-08:00")
},
```

My PHP code looks like:

```
$collection->update(array('account.email' => $email), array('$set' => array('dates.lastlogin' => new MongoDate())));
```

Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: Do they really reset randomly or can you spot a certain pattern? From what you have provided here it is really hard to figure out the specific problem.

Comment: I've tried looking for a pattern. I've created test accounts, and it seems sometimes when I save changes, it resets the date.. but not everytime. Sometimes when I login, it resets the date, but not every time.

Comment: I think you should further investigate the sections of the code that trigger the reset. And if you want our comments, please add sections from those files here!

Comment: Are there any off the wall reasons that PHP or MongoDB would reset the date to 1969?

Comment: I don't see any reasons why any client library should change data inside a database on its own. I'd say its 99.9% probability you do that data resetting unintentionally in your callbacks and 0.01% probability there is a genuine bug in MongoDB/MongoDB PHP client. -- In order to discover what's happening, you need to take a closer look into your actual code!

Comment: Very strange.. as that's the only places in my code that it's setting dates: upon login and upon saving the form. There is no other date code. Except for a php call to set the timezone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MongoDate()` represents a number of seconds since January 1st 1970 (ref: [MongoDate::__construct](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodate.construct.php)).

The date you are seeing is the result of passing a value of an undefined variable or 0 (aka the [unix epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)) to `MongoDate()`.

Normally this value would be saved in MongoDB as:

```
 ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z")
```

However, because you have set your timezone to `GMT -8` you are seeing the date offset by 8 hours, which becomes:

```
 ISODate("1969-12-31T16:00:00-08:00")
```

Comment: That makes complete sense! Is there something else I should be using instead of

`'dates.lastlogin' => new MongoDate()`

Comment: I don't get why it's passing an undefined variable or 0..?

Comment: @mrc0der: What version of the `mongo` PHP driver are you using?  Calling `new MongoDate()` in your code *should* be fine.  I would try adding some debug logging to your code to see what values are being saved.  Are you just calling `date_default_timezone_set()` beforehand to set the TZ ?  I tried this and it didn't affect my MongoDate() default .. not sure how to reproduce the outcome aside from passing an empty date.